# Exit activity after killing all threads android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I am trying to play with progress bars. I have this (below) simple activity which runs a progress bar N times one after the other, when I call Progress(N). It is working great but the problem I am facing is, if I press back button. I get into the mainActivity but the progress bars (the threads) are still running in background one after the other. As soon as they finish N loops, the intent is called and whatever I would be doing would be interrupted by this LOOP_OVER activity.

I tried solving this by my own. I tried using variable of Thread class (before I was directly doing it). And tried to interrupt() it at onDestroy() or even just before the intent is called but its not helping. How should I go about it?

```
public class Loop extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private CircleProgress circleProgress;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private TextView myView;
    private int started = 0, doneLoop=0;
    private Thread th;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loop);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        circleProgress = (CircleProgress) findViewById(R.id.circle_progress);

        myView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instruction);

        progressBar.setScaleY(3f);
        // Start long running operation in a background thread

        Progress(3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Below, everything I am just 
        th.interrupt();
        Loop.this.finish();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void Progress(final int numberOfRuns){
//        QueView.setText(Que);
        if(numberOfRuns == 0){
            th.interrupt();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Loop.this, LOOP_OVER.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            super.onDestroy();
            finish();
        }
        th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                genNextSet();
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the
                    //current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            circleProgress.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                myView.setText(Que);
                            }
                        });
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        //Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progressStatus = 0;

                Progress(numberOfRuns - 1);
            }
        });

        th.start();
    }


    private void genNextSet() {
        // so some cool here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a class variable that is shared among all threads.

Try to add something like this:

```
private Boolean LOOP = true;
```

then

```
while (progressStatus < 100 && LOOP) {
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
    LOOP = false
}
```

also

```
if(LOOP == true){
    // call intent
}
finish();
```

Comment: I am feeling bad for me. I could not think of this method. Actually I didn't try to think hard on that. Great thought btw. It worked. :) PS: I have edited the answer, accept the edit so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity does not get destroyed, if you press the "Back"-key, thus `onDestroy()` will not be called.
I'd override `onBackPressed()`, if I where you.
Alternatively, you could try to put it into the `onPause()`-method.

Comment: Tony in above answer suggested the same. I tried it but it didn't help. Read the last comment by me in Tony's answer. That's the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't override the back button pressed..try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
    th.interrupt();
    Loop.this.finish();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    super.onBackPressed();
// add finish() if you want to kill current activity
}
```

Comment: I did this but no help. I think, we need some management of threads. I don't know much neither in java or android specific. See if you can get me through it.

Comment: so the problem is that even if you go back the threads are still running right?because when u go to the progress bars they are completed or still increasing?

Comment: When i go back,I go back to main activity. And since finish() kill the main activity thread (I guess) and the threads created by Progress() are independent of main activity thread. So they run independently. And finally when all threads complete, we get the LOOP_OVER activity via intent. On more thing to note is the next thread is created by previews thread.

Comment: try to insert this in your threads..check if they are interrupted and if they are return..    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        return;}